# Xamarin Android WebView - JDE E1 Web Portal

Tags: javascript, android, xamarin, webview, jde

I am creating a Xamarin Android app that uses a simple webview that displays a JDE E1Menu.maf portal. The application is basically a website embedded in a simple WebView. I am able to log into the website, but when I get to the menu screen I cannot click on any of the buttons.

The portal has an IFrame with a table in it, where each table cell is a button that is fired via javascript. I cannot get the clicks to fire on the buttons in the table cell.

I have enabled javascript on the WebView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to fix your web view to support javascript and display the E1 JDE Portal:

```
webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true; // Enable javascripting
webView.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true; // Enable storage in DOM
webView.LoadUrl( "https://www.example.com/jde/" ); // Don't include the E1Menu.maf
```

This was tested and works.